# No matching route in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url, routes, uri

I have a `User` model that `has_many shifts` and `Shift` model which belong to a `user`. I'm trying to figure out why I get an no route match error.

In `routes.rb`:

```
get 'users/:id/shifts' => 'users#shifts', :as => :user_shifts 
resources :shifts
```

I created a route like:

```
user_shifts GET    /users/:id/shifts(.:format)          users#shifts
```

and I use it in my nav view to link to the page like:

```
<li><%= link_to "Shifts", user_shifts_path(@shifts) %></li>
```

in my `Users` controller:

```
def shifts
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @shifts = @user.shifts
end
```

Users/shifts.html.erb:

```
<% @shifts.each do |shift| %>
  <%= shift.start_time %>
<% end %>
```

The error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"shifts", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

but when I type in the url manually `http://localhost:3000/users/7/shifts`, it works?

I've tried everything with answers to related questions but can't seem to get anything to work. Can somebody please help?

Trace:

```
app/views/layouts/_nav.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_layouts__nav_html_erb__2914379975493970040_70146050606840'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3858195360324705958_70145981089600'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><%= link_to "Shifts", user_shifts_path(@shifts) %></li>
```

Here @shifts is an object. You need to pass User id in variable @shifts.
Its something like this

```
<li><%= link_to "Shifts", user_shifts_path(@user.id) %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

`<li><%= link_to "Shifts", user_shifts_path(@user) %></li>`

inplace of:

`<li><%= link_to "Shifts", user_shifts_path(@shifts) %></li>`

`user_shifts_path` expects `user`.

**Update:**

Try `<li><%= link_to "Shifts", user_shifts_path(id: @user.id) %></li>`

And if you encounter an error, please post the error message as well as the stacktrace.

Comment: doesn't work I tried ([@user, @shift]) it took the error away but then I received an error something like  `could notfind id`

Comment: `undefined method id' for nil:NilClas` I've also updated trace dont know if you need the full trace!

Comment: Make sure you have setup `@user` in your `action`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try :-

```
user_shifts_path(:id=>@shifts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
<%= link_to "Shifts", {:action=>"shifts", :controller=>"users", :id=>@user.id } %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Shifts", user_shifts_path(id: @user.id) %>
```

Comment: `undefined method id' for nil:NilClas` for both of them methods

Comment: it means @user from shifts method is nil. Please check it and make sure this can not be blank.